# Stream not building up using memcpy

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa

Not sure why I get a strlen that give 24 as apposed to 40?
thx

```
            char bufferData[1000];
            memset(bufferData, '\0', 1000);
            long j;
            long offset;
            double mice;

            mice = 32.45;
            j=0;
            offset = sizeof(double) * j;
            NSLog(@"offset: %d", offset);
            memcpy(bufferData+offset, &mice, sizeof(double));
            mice = 21.35;
            j=1;
            offset = sizeof(double) * j;
            NSLog(@"offset: %d", offset);
            memcpy(bufferData+offset, &mice, sizeof(double));
            mice = 11.55;
            j=2;
            offset = sizeof(double) * j;
            NSLog(@"offset: %d", offset);
            memcpy(bufferData+offset, &mice, sizeof(double));
            mice = 41.25;
            j=3;
            offset = sizeof(double) * j;
            NSLog(@"offset: %d", offset);
            memcpy(bufferData+offset, &mice, sizeof(double));
            mice = 51.50;
            j=4;
            offset = sizeof(double) * j;
            NSLog(@"offset: %d", offset);
            memcpy(bufferData+offset, &mice, sizeof(double));

            NSLog(@"sizeof(double): %d     strlen(bufferData): %d", sizeof(double), strlen(bufferData));
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `strlen` looks for a single byte set to zero, it stops when it reaches `41.25`, because five of its eight bytes are zero.

`41.25` converted to `double` becomes `0x4044A00000000000`

Comment: what should I use to find the length?

Comment: @jdl My best guess would be `sizeof(double) * (j+1)`.

Comment: you can't find the length if you are doing what you are doing, you need to keep track of it.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're memcpy()ing data in and there's a zero in your binary representation of one of the double values @ the 24th byte

Answer (score 2):

To convert binary data to a string you could use `sprintf()`.

Doing it the way you do, leaves the data in it's binary format which it totally different from its string representation.

Answer (score 1):

Strlen terminates on the first null byte it finds so it is not the appropriate function to find the number of bytes in your buffer.